# Help me identify this Chinese houseplant

Tags: identification, houseplants

A friend of mine living in Shenzhen China got this plant as a gift and I would like to see if I can buy one here in Sweden too. Therefor I need help identifying it so I know what to search for.

She only knew it as a "Small sunflower" but that didn't get me far googling.

She also mentioned that the flowers on the plant only lasts for a single day before being replaced by new ones the next day.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that's a [moss rose](https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Ftse2.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP.YPEV3qbUe-7alEgIuX9sIQHaEh%26pid%3DApi&f=1) (*Portulaca grandiflora*). It's grown as an outdoor annual in the US and has single, semi-double, and double flowered forms. Single-flowered forms are not as popular as the other forms. They reseed readily and can become kind of a pest if you don't use mulch in your garden. The flower habit you mention of opening for only a day is typical of the genus, as is the habit of flowers to not open on cloudy days.

[Here's](https://plants.ces.ncsu.edu/plants/portulaca-grandiflora/) some cultural information for growing them outdoors. Their main concern is having good drainage.

I also considered Helianthemum, but the leaves in that genus have a center midrib that the plant in your photo does not, and the flowers bloom for longer than a day. It's unusual to see moss rose as a houseplant, so lets see what other posters think of my ID.